# Forcing ggplot2 to include a cluster/group with 0 point for maintaining the consistent group number between two plots

Tags: r, ggplot2

ggplot2 does not include the group/cluster with no number.

Using ggplot2 to generate UMAP plots of two single cell RNAseq data.  They both have 19 clusters (rows) but one of them has one raw (raw #2) with zero. Now, ggplot2 skip the raw with 0 resulting in 18 clusters in one and 19 in another, and color assigned to each clusters does not match between two plots

I used a following ggplot2 script to plot UMAP data;

```
ggplot(pa.dt[type=="FT"], aes(UMAP_1, UMAP_2))+geom_point(size=2, shape=21, aes(fill=immgen.main))+scale_color_manual(values =color_clusters, aesthetics = "fill")
```

A following is an example of the plot with 19 clusters;

[image: 19Cluster UMAP plot]

This is the one with 18 clusters;

[image: 18Cluster UMAP]

Evidently, skipping one cluster (with 0) messes up the order of color assignment.  I'd appreciate any pointer to instruct ggplot2 to not to skip the row with 0.

Comment: I think you would need to convert the variable you're using for the fill aesthetic, `immgen.main`, to a factor, before feeding the data to either plot.

Comment: I tried this and did not work.  ggplot2 still skip the row with 0.  It is pain but I just have to manually take numbers corresponding the row of 0.